# xcode build settings for imported libraries (xcode 5)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I'm having a small issue with xcode (I'm assuming it's mostly due to being unfamiliar with xcode itself) and was hoping someone could lend me a hand.

I'm working with a group of people and we're using the GPUimage framework.

The problem is this:
For every person referencing GPUimage we get additional entries in the build settings for the xcode project.

For example build products path would be:

```
 /Users/username/project/application_name/GPUImage-master/GPUimage.framework
```

I would rather it be:

```
 /application_name/GPUImage-master/GPUimage.framework
```

The reason I want to fix this is because we need to package up our application and library together so that whoever wants to use it only needs to open the xcode project file to see what we've done (to mark it, school project).

Can anyone suggest what I should do or look for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the beginning of the user path:

```
$(SRCROOT)/application_name/GPUImage-master/GPUimage.framework
```

That should instruct XCode to use the user path of whoever is using the library

Hope this helps!